# Ideal CPU usage range in Linux

Tags: python, linux, performance, optimization, cpu-usage

I am developing an application for an Embedded system. It is based on Python. I am using top batch mode (top -p PID -b -n1) to calculate CPU usage by my process. The usage is between 30-50% for now. I agree it is too high but I am not sure what is a nominal number for Linux i.e. for any process what should be the ideal range for CPU usage (in percentage)? Knowing the number would greatly help me with optimization and/or making a transition to C/C++ if needed.

Comment: I'd say below 100% is good.

Comment: @KlausD. I also have few (5) other apps based on C running. Considering that I feel a range of 30-40% is what would be ideal for my app. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Your question and your understanding are highly subjective. Nobody can give you an objective answer on that. The below 100% I gave above are the only thing that matters in the end.